# Ints from text file are being read twice using fscanf to store into arrays

Tags: c

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *file  = fopen("Offices.txt", "r");
    char officeArray[10];
    int yCoordinate[10];
    int xCoordinate[10];

    int i=0;
    int x, y;
    char office;

    while(fscanf(file, "%c,%d,%d", &office, &x, &y) > 0)
    {
        officeArray[i] = office;
        xCoordinate[i] = x;
        yCoordinate[i] = y;
        printf("%c,%d,%d \n", officeArray[i], xCoordinate[i], yCoordinate[i]);
        i++;
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

I have a text file of node letters and coordinates:

```
A,1,1
B,1,5
C,3,7
D,5,5
E,5,1
```

My output is:

```
A,1,1 
,1,1
B,1,5 
,1,5
C,3,7 
,3,7 
D,5,5 
,5,5 
E,5,1 
,5,1
```

I can't tell why I am getting double the integer reads from the text file.

Comment: `fscanf(file, "%c,%d,%d", &office, &x, &y)` --> skip newline So`fscanf(file, " %c,%d,%d", &office, &x, &y)`

Comment: Are you saying I need a "\n" in my fscanf at the end?

Comment: Notice the space added before `%c` which consumes previous whitespace, incl `newline`.

Comment: @uoflPDTcodes `fscanf(file, "%c,%d,%d\n"` even OK

Comment: Thanks! I just needed to set the newline in the fscanf, that actually makes sense as to why it was doing that.

Comment: The last line in the file is not guaranteed to *have* a `newline`, better to use the space in the first comment.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think that no different with or without a newline at the end of the last line.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY you are right thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to include a newline command in my fscanf call.

```
while(fscanf(file, "%c,%d,%d\n", &office, &x, &y) > 0)
```